# On click, set cookie and check checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox

I have a screen with checkboxes. When the label is clicked a new window will be opened with text and an agree button. Once the user clicks the agree button, a cookie is set with a unique id referencing the checkbox. How do I check this checkbox based on if the cookie equals 1? Code is below.

```js
document.cookie = "doc_35_readit=0";
$('#have_read_agreement').on('click', function () {                    
  document.cookie = "doc_35_readit=1";
});
```

Now when the window is closed, I'm not sure how to check the checkbox. Something like this maybe?

```
if (cookie("doc_35_readit") == "1") {
  $(".doc_35_readit").click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Initial checkbox: -->
  <input type="checkbox"
    id="agreementChecker-0"
    name="agreeCheck-0"
    value="35"
    class="mandatory agreeChecker doc_35_readit"/>

<!-- New Window opens with text, button at bottom: -->
  <p align="center" id="have_read_agreement" style="text-align:center;font-size:20px;">
    <a href="javascript:window.close()" class="btn-read">I have read this agreement and accept all terms and conditions.</a>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attribute `checked` of input:checkbox element to either true or false if you want it checked or unchecked accordingly.

```js
$('input[name=test]').attr('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the cookie by name you need to create your own `get` function like :

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

That will parse the cookies and gives you the ability to select from them by name like :

```
getCookie("doc_35_readit")
```

Then your condition will work like :

```
if (getCookie("doc_35_readit") == "1") {
    $(".doc_35_readit").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is very possible to do with native javascript only.

but because you seems not expert to create cookies and you are using jquery

i recommend you to use this plugin: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

then you can try this example:

```
<button id="delete">delete cookie</button>
<button id="display">display cookie</button>
<textarea></textarea>

<div id="modal"><h1>this will display only if user not accept yet</h1>are you agree with our ToS? <input type="checkbox" id="agreementChecker-0" name="agreeCheck-0" value="35" class="mandatory agreeChecker doc_35_readit"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){


    $('#agreementChecker-0').change(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            Cookies.set('doc_35_readit', 1);
            $('#modal').hide();
        }else{
            Cookies.set('doc_35_readit', 0);
            $('#modal').show();
        }
    });

    if(Cookies.get('doc_35_readit')== 1){
        $('#modal').hide();
    }

    $('#display').click(function(){
        var c = (Cookies.get('doc_35_readit') ==undefined) ? 'not found':Cookies.get('doc_35_readit');
        $('textarea').val(c);
        console.log(Cookies.get()); //show all possible cookie in console
    });

    $('#delete').click(function(){
        Cookies.remove('doc_35_readit');
        $('#modal').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

> PS: you can try to refresh your page to see your cookies is already set or not